# Верстка из 2 строк

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Страница состоит из 2 блоков.

Нижний блок(голубой) на рисунке должен быть фиксированный.
Верхний блок (красный) на рисунке подстраивается под высоту окна браузера.

Подскажите как реализовать без js, при этом страница не должна скролиться.

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="main"></div>
        <div class="action-block">
            <div class="action-step"></div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

В данном случае `action-block` - это голубой блок, а футер будет внутри него.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ys9hkzsx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Наложение на padding

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding-bottom: 7em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

footer {
  height: 7em;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

## Применить calc для вычисления высоты

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 7em);
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

footer {
  height: 7em;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

## Использовать flexbox

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 7em;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

## Использовать абсолютное позиционирование

```css
main {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 7em;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 7em;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Разверните на всю страницу, чтобы увидеть результат.
Остаётся задать желаемую ширину вашему футеру.

```css
.main {
  background: tomato;
  height: calc(100vh - 250px);
}
.action-block {
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="action-block">
    <div class="action-step"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. параметр `100vh` - относительно новый, потому не во всех браузерах будет работать

Comment: придумываете костыли расчета, что за ерунда ребят, flex кто то отменил? Пора бы уже обуздать его мощь

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.action-block
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    
  </div>
  <div class="action-block">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

[Резиновый двухколоночный (легко переделать в двухстроковый) макет](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-dvukhkolonochnyi-maket)